# Prove that a Lagrangian that Induces a Linear Elliptic Euler-Lagrange PDE has Unique Form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

I am asking if existence, taken as an assumption for a solution $L$ to the linear operator equation $$\mathcal{E}L = F$$ with conditions on $F$, implies further conditions on $F$ and uniqueness of a generic form for the terms in $L$ not annihilated by $\mathcal{E}$.

The variational problem giving rise to the operator equation is to find a stationary solution $u$ that minimizes the action functional $$I[u]=\int_{\Omega}{L(Du,u,x)dx}$$

This induces the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial u}-\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_i u)} \right)}=0$$

and the corresponding operator $$\mathcal{E}=\partial_u-\nabla\cdot \partial_{\partial_i u}$$

This can be adjusted to accommodate any number of higher order derivatives ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Several_functions_of_several_variables_with_higher_derivatives)). A nice lemma would justify only allowing dependence up to $Du$, not $D^2u$ and higher.

Suppose $L$ induces Euler-Lagrange equations that are linear-elliptic. In the operator formulation this is $\mathcal{E}L=F=0$ where $$F(Du,u,x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sum_{j=1}^n{ a_{ij}(x)\partial_{ij}u }}+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k(x)\partial_{k}u+c(x)u-f(x) $$

with smoothness and other conditions on $a,b,c,f$ to ensure ellipticity. Can we prove that

1. the divergence of the $k$th column of the $a_{i,j}$ matrix is such that
   $$
   b_k=\nabla\cdot a_{.,k}
   $$
   or more generally
2. the (Lagrangian) function $L$ has the form
   $$
   L(Du,u,x)=\frac{c(x)u^2}{2}-f(x)u-\text{Tr}\left(A(x)(\nabla u \otimes \nabla u)  \right) + L_0
   $$
   where

   - $c,f$ are some smooth functions,
   - $A_{i,j}$ is some $n\times n$ matrix of smooth functions and
   - $L_0$ is such that $L_0$ $\mathcal{E}L_0=0$?

The converse is easy enough to verify. (Note, the $a_{i,j}$ are $(1+\delta_{i,j})A_{i,j}$, since applying $\mathcal{E}$ introduces a $2$ on the diagonal where there is none off diagonal). Try as I might I can't find any way to add other terms into $L$ that produce linear elliptic terms in the Euler-Lagrange equation ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837467/)). But I also can't see all the way through the logic for why this should not be possible.

It seems 'obvious' that $F$ restricts $L$ to a quadratic polynomial in $Du,u$ with smooth function coefficients, and that each possible term is either captured in (2) or forced to have coefficient zero from incompatibility with $F$. I'm looking for confirmation (or disconfirmation) of this logic.

**Edit**. Could someone at least elucidate what kind of problem this is and what relevant theory is helpful understanding it? I understand that the variational problem in $u$ has its own peculiarities, and that $\mathcal{E}L=0$ is merely a related PDE. But what kind of problem is $\mathcal{E}L=F$ where, instead of solving for $u$, we are solving for $L$? What is known about this problem in general? Is there a Green's Function approach that makes sense to find $L$ constructively? Or at least one that shows existence and maybe demonstrates some properties?

Answer (score 2):

**Premises to the answer**

The question you are asking is not an easy one as it is a version of the ***inverse problem of the calculus of variation*** (see [1] and [3] for some bibliographical references). In the form of your operator equation, the problem is hardly solvable, but if you leave the classic formulation of the problem and adopt a generalised one, you can get a necessary and sufficient condition on $F$ in order for your problem to have a solution. The **generalised inverse problem of the calculus of variation** asks for a solution of the following first variation equation
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dm}{d\!}
\frac{\delta\mathfrak{L}}{\delta u }[u](\varphi) = \mathfrak{F}[u](\varphi) \label{2}\tag{FV}
$$
where

- $\mathfrak{L}$ is a functional on a given Banach (or more general) space) $E$: precisely, in our starting problem
  $$
  \mathfrak{L}(u)=I(u)=\int_{\Omega}{L(Du,u,x)\dm x}
  $$
- $\mathfrak{F}$ is an operator mapping the domain of $\mathfrak{L}$ to the dual $E^\ast$ of $E$. In our starting problem,
  $$
  \mathfrak{F}[u](\varphi)\triangleq\langle \mathfrak{F}[u],\varphi\rangle= \int_{\Omega}{F(Du,u,x)}{\varphi(x)}{\dm x}
  $$
- the left side of \eqref{2} is the [functional derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives/349584#349584) of $\mathfrak{L}$, i.e. the operator $E\to E^\ast$ defined as
  $$
  \frac{\delta\mathfrak{L}}{\delta u }[u](\varphi)\triangleq D\mathfrak{L}[u](\varphi) \triangleq \left.\frac{\dm\,}{\dm \epsilon} \mathfrak{L}(u+\epsilon \varphi)\right|_{\epsilon=0}
  $$
  The functional derivative can be nonlinear: however in most applications, including the one we are dealing, it is linear and thus  it is at least a [Gâteaux derivative](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative).

This problem is known to be solvable if and only if $\mathfrak{F}$ is a *potential operator* (and a Gâteaux derivative, see [1], pp. 5-6, §11 pp. 92-93, and [3], §3 pp. 152-153). Being a potential operator means that, for any real curve in $E$ i.e. any function $\varepsilon\mapsto u(\varepsilon)\in E$ (here we assume $\varepsilon\in [0,1]$ without restriction to generality), the value of the functional
$$
\int\limits_0^1 \mathfrak{F}[u(\epsilon)]\left( \frac{\dm\,}{\dm\epsilon} u(\varepsilon)\right)\dm\epsilon =
\int\limits_0^1 \left\langle\mathfrak{F}[u(\epsilon)], \frac{\dm\,}{\dm\epsilon} u(\varepsilon)\right\rangle\dm\epsilon
$$
depends only on the functions $u(\varepsilon)|_{\varepsilon=0}\triangleq u_0$ and $u(\varepsilon)|_{\varepsilon=1}\triangleq u_1$. This in turn can be shown to be equivalent to the fact that the functional derivative of $\mathfrak{F}$ is symmetric (see [1], pp. 5-6, §11 pp. 92-93, [2], §5.2 pp. 55-58, and [3], §3 pp. 152-153), i.e.
$$
\left\langle\frac{\delta\mathfrak{F}}{\delta u }[u](u_0),u_1\right\rangle=\left\langle\frac{\delta\mathfrak{F}}{\delta u }[u](u_1),u_0\right\rangle\label{3}\tag{Sym}
$$
and this condition implies that
$$
\mathfrak{L}(u) \triangleq \mathfrak{L}(u_0) +
\int\limits_0^1 \left\langle\mathfrak{F}[u(\epsilon)], \frac{\dm\,}{\dm\epsilon} u(\varepsilon)\right\rangle\dm\epsilon\label{5}\tag{Lag}
$$
where $u(\epsilon) \triangleq u_0 + \varepsilon (u-u_0)$.
This is the condition needed in order to answer the question.

**Answer to the question**

> Can we prove that
>
> 1. the divergence of the $k$th column of the $a_{i,j}$ matrix is such that
>    $$
>    b_k=\nabla\cdot a_{.,k}
>    $$
>    or more generally
> 2. the (Lagrangian) function $L$ has the form
>    $$
>    L(Du,u,x)=\frac{c(x)u^2}{2}-f(x)u-\text{Tr}\left(A(x)(\nabla u \otimes \nabla u)  \right) + L_0
>    $$
>    where
>
>    - $c,f$ are some smooth functions,
>    - $A_{i,j}$ is some $n\times n$ matrix of smooth functions and
>    - $L_0$ is such that $L_0$ $\mathcal{E}L_0=0$?

The condition
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\divg}{\nabla\cdot}
b_k=\nabla\cdot a_{.,k} \iff \mathbf b(x) = \divg\mathbf{A}(x)
$$
is necessary and sufficient for [the linear PDE to be self-joint or, equivalently, symmetric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940140/on-the-self-adjoint-form-for-the-general-elliptic-pde/3944943#3944943): therefore we have that
$$
\begin{split}
F(Du,u,x) &=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sum_{j=1}^n{ a_{ij}(x)\partial_{ij}u }}+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k(x)\partial_{k}u+c(x)u-f(x) \\
& = \divg \big(\mathbf{A}(x)\nabla u\big)+c(x)u-f(x)
\end{split}
$$
and this is equivalent to say that
$$
\begin{split}
\mathfrak{F}[u](\varphi) = \langle \mathfrak{F}[u],\varphi\rangle 
&= \int_{\Omega}{F(Du,u,x)}{\varphi(x)}{\dm x}\\
&= -\int_{\Omega} \big\langle\mathbf{A}(x)\nabla u, \nabla \varphi\big\rangle {\dm x} + \int_{\Omega} [c(x)u-f(x)] \varphi {\dm x}.
\end{split}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{split}
\left\langle\frac{\delta\mathfrak{F}}{\delta u }[u](u_0),u_1\right\rangle =\left\langle\frac{\delta\mathfrak{F}}{\delta u }(u_0),u_1\right\rangle &= -\int_{\Omega} \big\langle\mathbf{A}(x)\nabla u_0, \nabla u_1 \big\rangle {\dm x} + \int_{\Omega} c(x)u_0u_1 {\dm x}\\
& = -\int_{\Omega} \big\langle\mathbf{A}(x)\nabla u_1, \nabla u_0 \big\rangle {\dm x} + \int_{\Omega} c(x)u_1u_0 {\dm x}
\\ &= \left\langle\frac{\delta\mathfrak{F}}{\delta u }(u_1),u_0\right\rangle =\left\langle\frac{\delta\mathfrak{F}}{\delta u }[u](u_1),u_0\right\rangle
\end{split}
$$
thus \eqref{3} is verified (I dropped the dependence on the generic $u\in E$ as $\mathfrak{F}$ is a linear functional of this argument: the condition is not restricted to linear operators). In turn the symmetry/self-adjointness of $F$ is equivalent to \eqref{3} which is equivalent to the fact that $F$ is the Euler-Lagrange operator associated to a given Lagrangian function $L$ solving the operator equation $\mathcal{E} L =F$. For the second part of the question, formula \eqref{5} gives the exact form of the Lagrangian function $L$, which happens to be the same one you asked about, i.e.
$$
L(Du,u,x)=\frac{c(x)u^2}{2}-f(x)u-\text{Tr}\left(\mathbf A(x)(\nabla u \otimes \nabla u)  \right) + L_0
$$
where the involved quantities have the same meaning as above.

**References**

[1] Vladimir Mikhailovich Filippov, *[Variational principles for nonpotential operators](https://www.ams.org/books/mmono/077/)*. With an appendix by the author and V. M. Savchin, Translated from the Russian by J. R. Schulenberger. Transl. ed. by Ben Silver, Translations of Mathematical Monographs, 77. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). pp. xiii+239 (1989), ISBN: 0-8218-4529-2. [MR1013998](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1013998), [Zbl 0682.35006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0682.35006).

[2]  Mikhail Mordukhovich Vaĭnberg, *Variational methods for the study of nonlinear operators. With a chapter on Newton’s method by L.V. Kantorovich and G.P. Akilov*, translated and supplemented by Amiel Feinstein, Holden-Day Series in Mathematical Physics. San Francisco-London- Amsterdam: Holden-Day, Inc. pp. x+323 (1964), [MR0176364](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0176364), [ZBL0122.35501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0122.35501).

[3] Enzo Tonti, "[Extended variational formulation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506200630/http://www.discretephysics.org/DEPOSITO/Tonti-russi.pdf)", Vestnik Rossiĭskogo Universiteta Druzhby Narodov, Seriya Matematika 2, No. 2, 148-162 (1995). [Zbl 0965.35036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0965.35036).

Comment: Amazing, than you so much Danielle!

Comment: I'm glad that you like it. I also apologise for the fact that I was not able to came up with this answer before you put a bounty on it, so you lost experience point, but I've been quite busy.

Comment: I'm only too happy to use my reputation points to get good discourse on the site! I think I earned points for the response I posted to the related question I linked, even though I couldn't prove that the solution I constructed was unique and fully generic